# Как в textbox отображать данные построчно?

Tags: c#, вывод

Банальный код:

```
int b=0;
while (b<1000)
{
   b+=1;
   textBox1.Text += b.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

выводит в боксе сразу 1000 чисел после выполнения, а это не совсем удобно, так как хочется, чтобы отображал каждую итерацию. То есть хочется добиться результата, как через консоль.
И заодно сопутствующий вопрос. Почему метод `.AppendText` работает значительно быстрее `.Text`, то есть логичнее использовать его или там есть какие-то ограничения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу: нужно установить свойство [WordWrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap(v=vs.110).aspx) в `true`.

По второму: конкатенация строк [очень медленная](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestConcatenation.aspx) (посмотрите на таблицу в разделе Results) операция. Для этого лучше использовать, например, [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) (что скорее все и делает `AppendText`), т.е. добавить в него все, что надо, а потом уже сделать присваивание свойству `Text` Вашего `TextBox'a`.

---

**UPDATE**

Про фоновое выполнение-то совсем забыл написать!
Воспользуйтесь классом [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx), да и вообще про [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) будет не лишним почитать.
Получится что-то такое

```
private void DoWork()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
      Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppentText(i.ToString())));
   }
}
```

И где-то запускаем задачу

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork);
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Но, я забыл упомянуть, что только начал изучать программирвоание(еще не дошел до классов и функций) и выбрал WPF, а не Forms чисто из-за редактора, который визуально, помоему разнообразней.   
Так вот, можно ли Invoke использовать в WPF или проще работать с Forms и не заморачиваться? Просто, моя проблема возникла когдя я хотел банально логировать действия программы.

Comment: Если это `WPF`, то там есть [Dispatcher ][1]. А вообще в `WPF` не надо напрямую обращаться к контролам, там нужно использовать 
[Binding][2].

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx
[2]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: +1, но: следует отчётливо понимать, что «медленная» конкатенация строк на несколько порядков быстрее любой UI-операции.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, заполнение сразу тысячей записей наблюдается оттого, что после добавления текста к `textBox1.Text` не обновляется форма (это происходит после выполнения действия). Мне кажется, тут можно воспользоваться `BackgroundWorker`'ом, а в отдельном фоновом потоке  сделать

```
int b = 1;
while (b <= 1000)
{
    myForm.Invoke (new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text += b.ToString() + Environment.NewLine));
    b++;
}
```